# What additional tackling rules could the NFL adopt from Rugby in order to improve safety?

Tags: rules, football

For many years the [NFL has been changing the rules](https://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/rules-changes/health-safety-rules-changes/) to improve player safety.
How do tackling rules differ between Rugby and NFL?
What additional tackling rules could the NFL adopt from Rugby in order to improve safety?

From [this article](https://www.florugby.com/articles/6745817-rugby-vs-football-which-is-more-dangerous), I assume that primary rule change would be to require "players [to] wrap up when attempting to tackle".
What might be other changes?
What is the likelihood that football would adopt these additional changes?

Comment: Your question title and your actual question don't seem to have anything to do with each other.  Could you please make them match?

Comment: Update title to the more specific focus of my inquiry.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest safety improvement the NFL could make by far would be to remove helmets. While this sounds paradoxical, helmets allow the kind of plays which result in concussions. Remove them (and obviously forbid any tackles above the chest area) and you'd have a much safer game; see for instance, [this article from The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/sport/2019/sep/06/helmets-dont-eliminate-concussions-its-time-for-the-nfl-to-ditch-them).

The chance of this happening is probably just about zero though.